# MediaRecorder Audio Delay

Tags: android, audio, delay, mediarecorder

While there are multiple questions about this subjecton stackoverflow and all over the web, like:

- [MediaRecorder class starts recording audio after slight delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533886/mediarecorder-class-starts-recording-audio-after-slight-delay)
- [Why is MediaRecorder delaying the start of recording?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937740/why-is-mediarecorder-delaying-the-start-of-recording)
- [MediaRecorder Silence at Beginning of Recording (Delay?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043799/mediarecorder-silence-at-beginning-of-recording-delay)
- [Issue 15953: MediaRecorder class starts recording audio after slight delay](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15953)

These links are all from like 2010 to about 2013, whereas no definitive solution has yet been found.

My situation looks like this:

1. User Clicks on 'Record'
2. I start polling the getMaxAmplitude()
3. When the amplitude is bigger than some value, lets say 5000, I start my MediaRecorder. (functional requirement)
4. The MediaRecorder both records Video AND Audio.
5. User clicks 'Stop recording' saving the output as an .mp4 file.

I expected the MediaRecorder to record both the video and the audio at all times. Unfortunately this is not the case.

As seen in the first link there is a delay, thus not recording the beginning (which is the most important part of the recording in my case). 
A possible solution would be to use the AudioRecorder or the RehearsalAudioRecorder. They, unfortunately, only record Audio.

How would I counter this problem?